# F-Droid 0.91 disappears after being installed as system app on cyanogenmod 12

Tags: cyanogenmod, system-apps, f-droid

I tried to install F-Droid (0.91) as system app on Cyanogenmod 12. The installation succeed but after that the F-Droid icon disappears.

Of course i tried to restart more times, i tried also to reinstall F-Droid as standard app from an apk but it crasches when i try to start it... probably for a conflict.

Someone knows if i can try something, i.e. where i can try to find the executable?

Comment: Worth a try: Remove the `.apk` completely from your device (use e.g. TiBu to delete it), download [the latest `.apk` from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/FDroid.apk), copy it to `/system/app` (or where it belongs to on Lollipop – I'm not sure if it must be in the "priv" folder instead; check where it's currently), then reboot. Let me know whether this worked out.

Comment: @Izzy I tested your solution in my CM12 exactly, it works, and the `.apk` should be in `/system/app` since I see no reason for `/system/priv-app`. What's bugging me is TiBu just hung up (doing processing for eternity) when I tried to convert FDroid into a system app. May be TiBu isn't updated, I need to check.  // And I think you should get your hands on Lollipop soon, since you end up relying on an under for your tries. :)

Comment: And I forgot to mention that the latest F-Droid is v0.92 and 0.91.

Comment: @Firelord Thanks for your confirmation! I just returned home, and promptly converted my comment to a full-fledged answer. And yes, the version number was the first thing I've noticed – just hving updated the app myself recently :)

Answer (score 3):

You can solve that as follows:

1. Completely delete the old F-Droid app (e.g. uninstall using *Titanium Backup*)
2. Get [the latest .apk from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/FDroid.apk) and put it on your device
   <sup>(either download directly with your Android web browser, or use `adb push`)</sup>
3. Login to your device either via a [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal) app or using `adb shell`
4. Obtain root privileges by executing the command `su`
5. Make sure to have the `/system` partition mounted read-write

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /system
   ```
6. Now get the downloaded `FDroid.apk` to `/system/app`. Change to the directory you've downloaded/pushed it to and run:

   ```
   cp FDroid.apk /system/app
   ```
7. Secure your `/system` partition again

   ```
   mount -o remount,ro /system
   ```
8. Reboot

Now F-Droid should be available to you again. Enjoy the great pool of open source Android apps!

Comment: +1, but I ignored steps 3-7 and used a file explorer like ES Explorer to do the copy-paste. :) But yeah, that `ro` security is important.

Comment: @Firelord Yes, I had that in mind – but preferred a more "generic" solution :) Your command adds the other option, so I'll give it a +1 as well :D

Comment: It hasn't worked for me :( : `adb shell` `shell@totoro:/ $ su` `root@totoro:/ # mount -o remount,rw /system` `root@totoro:/ # cd /mnt/sdcard/download/` `root@totoro:/mnt/sdcard/download # cp FDroid.apk                                                           /system/app                                        
cp: can't create '/system/app/FDroid.apk': Read-only file system`

Comment: .... even after the `mount` command, when i check with `cat /proc/mounts` the path `/system` remains in read-only: `/dev/block/mtdblock8 /system yaffs2 ro,seclabel,relatime 0 0`

Comment: I'm pretty confused: if you cannot mount `/system` read-write, there's not much you can do – so you should first figure why that part fails (hint: check the logs, e.g. using `logcat` – see our [logging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) for details if needed).